# Why mocked class instantiated in module scope says it wasn't instantiated?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a `SlackClient` class that I instantiate in my main program `main.py` in the module scope, to be re-used throughout the module (kind of like a singleton) to send messages via Slack. However I cannot get the test working that mocks out the client (I don't want the client sending messages to Slack every time I run my unit tests) and tests that the client was instantiated with the correct auth token.

The Slack client:

```
## slack_client.py

class SlackClient:
    def __init__(self, auth_token):
        pass

def instantiate_client():
    get_token_from_secrets = lambda: "mock-auth-token"
    return SlackClient(get_token_from_secrets())
```

The main program where the client is instantiated and used:

```
## main.py
from slack import instantiate_client

slack_client = instantiate_client()
# Then in this file I do some logic that calls the slack_client singleton.
```

The test file where I test the args `SlackClient()` was instantiated with:

```
import core
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

@patch("core.slack_client")
def test_instantiation(slack_client):
    # This should succeed, but it fails
    slack_client.assert_called_once_with("mock-auth-token")

test_instantiation()
```

How can I test the arguments used to instantiate a class in the module scope?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have some project structure that looks like this:

```
project
|_ core
|  |_ __init__.py
|  |_ slack_client.py
|_ main.py
|_ test.py
```

If so, you're patching the whole `core.slack_client` module when you should be patching the `core.slack_client.SlackClient` class.

The test file should look like:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

# patch the object with this namespace
@patch("core.slack_client.SlackClient")
def test_instantiation(slack_client):
    slack_client.assert_called_once_with("mock-auth-token")

test_instantiation()
```

If this works, you don't need to import `core` at all, as mock.patch will take care of patching that namespace. Alternatively, if I'm mistaken about your project structure, you might need to use `mock.patch.object` instead of `mock.patch`:

```py
import core
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

# patch the "SlackClient" object in the "core" module
@patch(core, "SlackClient")
def test_instantiation(slack_client):
    slack_client.assert_called_once_with("mock-auth-token")

test_instantiation()
```